# PHP / Javascript and Loading Bar

Tags: javascript, php, loops, progress-bar

I am trying to make a simple loader bar, that will update as a PHP loop runs through its processes. The simple code is below, my issue is the php loop loads completely before loading the bar to 100%. For example I run the script the page loads and it shoots to 100% where as it supposed to go 10% 20% 30% etc. Is there a way to force the output during my PHP loop?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    #ProgressBar {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #BarColour {
      width: 0%;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <h1>Progress Bar</h1>

    <div id="ProgressBar">
      <div id="BarColour"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function move(amount) {
      var elem = document.getElementById("BarColour");
      elem.style.width = amount + '%';
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    Sleep(0.4);
    $counter = $x *10;
    echo "<script>move($counter)</script>";
    } 
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance 
Eddie

Comment: PHP would have finished counting to 100 before it outputs the html, you should do this all in javascript.

Comment: php runs completly server side before any thing is sent to the browser

Comment: it **is** possible to force the output with ob_flush, but that's the perfect example of an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Ok guys I fully understand now thanks. Is there any reliable to solution to having a real time process/update screen when using a PHP loop? Or is the fact its executed first always going to be the stumbling block?